# How to convert a unicode key name so amazon-s3 will recognize it?

Tags: python, unicode, amazon-s3, boto

In a django application, I am receiving a POST variable with a name of a file uploaded into amazon s3.

But I receive the key in unicode, and when I pass the key to boto and amazon s3, nothing is returned. However if I list the bucket with boto, and get the key from the list, then amazon s3 returns the object expected.

So my question is, how can I convert my unicode keyname into the same encoding of the key that boto has so that amazon will give me the object.

How can I know what encoding the boto key is in?

Thanks a lot for any insight, this one is driving me crazy. It all worked fine before we added the forward slash and I can't see why that would make a difference.

Here is the code from the terminal:

```
>>> unicode_key_name
u'missionuploads/tom-mission-4d8f9da9122ac21c17000002-4_4_11_9_38_PM.jpg'
>>> boto_key_name
'missionuploads/tom-mission-4d8f9da9122ac21c17000002-4_4_11_9_37_PM.jpg'
>>> len(unicode_key_name)
70
>>> len(boto_key_name)
70
>>> unicode_key = bucket.get_key(unicode_key_name.encode('utf-8'))
>>> unicode_key
>>> unicode_key = bucket.get_key(unicode_key_name.encode('ascii'))
>>> unicode_key
>>> boto_key = bucket.get_key(boto_key_name)
>>> boto_key
<Key: user.media.eu,missionuploads/tom-mission-4d8f9da9122ac21c17000002-4_4_11_9_37_PM.jpg>
```

-------- EDIT ----------

Passing the unicode string works fine there is no need to convert it, just make sure you are searching for the right key name!

Since I just received the key name on the server side I assumed it was correct, but the error appears to be in the app side saving with one name and then sending a newly created name (one minute different) to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'37'` and `'38'` are different strings. It will probably work fine when you use the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the extra pair of eyes Ignacio, I even diffed all of the special characters and skipped over the obvious, since I never considered I would be getting the wrong file name. Cheers